# What does ":" do when used in export env variable?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, environment-variables

I am just trying to following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1447246/how-to-solve-please-make-sure-libcudnn-cnn-infer-so-8-is-in-your-library-path) post.

I have replaced "/some/directory/" by "/usr/lib/x86_64_linux-gnu/", resulting in

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64_linux-gnu/
```

Now when I type

```
printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

it prints

```
:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I wonder if the : is correct, and if not what I have to do differently.

I am confused why the author used

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/directory/
```

What does the "$" and the ":" do?

Comment: the export includes the current value ($LD_LIBRARY_PATH where the '$' highlights it's talking about a variable) and new directory which is added as another place to search; the `:` acts as a delimiter between directories to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a collection of paths, each ending in a directory (hence you don't include specific libraries like libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8 in it) where libraries are searched for, like the normal PATH which lists places, where to look for executable programs.

The colon (:) is the delimiter between the paths, if there is more than one.

The

```
export xy_PATH=$xy_PATH:/abc
```

pattern is a common pattern, when a system wide setting is declared in a system wide config file in /etc for example, but later expanded by a user specific config file in his /$HOME/.xyconf. The user takes, what is already defined, and extends it.

The colon is an automatic delimiter for the shell, since it can't be part of a variable name. This makes it easy to extend it. Otherwise, you would have to write `export xy_PATH=${xy_PATH}:/abc`. Also note, that an empty part in front of the colon is harmless which makes the composition robust.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has just been added to the knowledge of an AI chat bot. :-D